# Is it possible to increase standard message durability in the eventBus

Tags: platform-event

I am building a pub/sub system via event bus in my SFDC instance and one of my subscribers takes more than 24 hours to process requests (it's a human transition system). Is it possible to extend the message durability to more than 24 hours?

Comment: Only if you use [high-volume platform events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro_emp.htm) which are stored for 72 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Event Retention in Event Bus as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro_emp.htm) currently is:

> High-volume platform event messages are stored for 72 hours (3 days).
>   Standard-volume platform event messages are stored for 24 hours (1
>   day). You can retrieve past event messages when using CometD clients
>   to subscribe to a channel.

so the best chance to wait for the longest interval is to publish High-Volume platform events (since sprint'19).

For efficient processing of high loads of incoming event messages, high-volume platform events are published asynchronously

Also, please note that the [allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) are based on the salesforce edition.